# Does a smooth affine curve factor through its integral model?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically connected affine curve over a number field $k$ and let $C$ be its smooth compactification. I am trying to prove that the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow C$ induces an injective map of adelic points $X(\mathbb{A}_k) \rightarrow C(\mathbb{A}_k)$. Of course if we start with an adelic point $\alpha = (P_v) \in X(\mathbb{A}_k)$, then the corresponding morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{A}_k \rightarrow X$ can be composed with the inclusion to obtain an adelic point of $C$.

However, if we try to look at it local field by local field, I can't seem to piece things up. Recall that the adelic points of affine $X$ can be written as follows: there exists a finite set $S$ of places containing the infinite places such that
$$X(\mathbb{A}_k) \rightarrow \prod_{v \in S} X(k_v) \times \prod_{v \notin S} \mathcal{X}(\mathcal{O}_v)$$ is a bijection. Here $\mathcal{X}$ is a smooth integral model of $X$ over the ring of $S$-integers $\mathcal{O}_v$ of the local field $k_v$ such that $X \cong \mathcal{X} \times_{\mathcal{O}_v} k_v$. At a finite place, an integral point $P_v \in \mathcal{X}(\mathcal{O}_v)$ corresponds to a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_v \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$, which I am trying to show would then lead to a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,k_v \rightarrow C$. Of course we can precompose $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_v \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ with the canonical morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\, k_v \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_v$. And I suppose we then need to compose with $\mathcal{X} \rightarrow C$ to finish things off.

But what is this map $\mathcal{X} \rightarrow C$? Is it the one such that precomposing with $X \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ (given in the pull-back) would give us the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow C$?

Comment: I may have missed something, but isn’t this just the fact that an open immersion is a monomorphism of schemes?

Comment: @Aphelli Indeed, but here I was trying to verify at every local field, or is this wrong?

Comment: @oleout - Im familiar with the Neron model of an elliptic curve over a number field, but here you speak of  "a smooth integral model of $X$" over the local field $k_v$ - can you briefly describe how you construct this (with references)?

Comment: @oleout: in this case, you certainly need to spread $C$ out as well (and you almost certainly need to take the colimits as $S$ grows).

Comment: @hm2020 It's over the spectrum of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_S$. Maybe I'm careless with the term "smooth", but $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite type scheme sometimes called the *integral model* of $X$. A reference can be found in Poonen's *Rational points on varieties*, Chapter 2.6.3.

Comment: @Aphelli Okay I will try to write it explicitly, but anyhow, we will get an injective map $X(\mathbb{A}_k) \hookrightarrow C(\mathbb{A}_k)$, and that we can view a point $(P_v)$ of $X(\mathbb{A}_k)$ directly as a point of $C(\mathbb{A}_k)$, right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! $X(\mathbb{A}_k) \rightarrow C(\mathbb{A}_k)$ will be injective and so you can see it as an inclusion of sets.